# while using ng select, getting warning about 'defineInjectable'

Tags: angular

[console output with warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUoHQ.png)

Whenever using the `ng select` module in my app, at compile time I'm getting this warning/error.

Comment: Looks like npm doesn't have proper version of that module and it's dependencies. Try to uninstall and reinstall. If that doesn't work delete all node modues then reinstall everything. If that doesn't work install latest. The npm eco system is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm update --save` to update to latest version of each module and to ensure all module versions are compatibile with each other.

Sounds like the `ng select` version is for a newer version of Angular. I can't know because I didn't see your `package.json` contents.